# what is the purpose of using template.library() and @register.filter() in the below code

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am new to django framework. I have a doubt with the package of library. can any one explain me about the **template.library()** function and in what purpose we are used **@register.filter()** before starting a function. I have defined the code below.

```
   from django import template
   register = template.Library()
   @register.filter()

   def boldcoffee(value):
       '''Returns input wrapped in HTML <b> tags'''
       return '<b>%s</b>' % value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/).  It allows you run your code in the template:

```
{{ some_var|boldcoffee }}
```

If `some_var` is "blah" then the rendered output will be:

```
<b>blah</b>
```

You can check the [built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/) for example of what can be done with this technique.

Comment: can you explain briefly in which purpose it will be used

Comment: using {{ some_var|boldcoffee }} we can directly called the method name of boldcoffee() from template page. Then why do we use @register.filter() here.

Comment: `boldcoffee()` is not a method of the `some_var` so we can't call it directly like `{{ some_var.boldcoffee }}`.  When we register this function as a filter we can apply this function to any var/constant in the template.  For example: `{{ "some string"|boldcoffee }}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the custom template tag which is provided by django.

You can make own template tag and filter in django.

So register is used to add your custom filter in library.